# LibreOffice Macro error that i dont know how to fix

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I need a macro that changes the active sheet, prints the new active sheet, and then goes back to the original sheet.

and it worked, but now every time i open the document and try using the macro it shows an error on the "`ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut From:=1, To:=1, Copies:=1`" line.
if i delete a letter and write it again it works fine again.

I have been searching if there is another way of getting the macro to print the active sheet without a confirmation screen but im at a loss.
Please if someone knows in what way the code should be changed id apreciate it.

I've already explained it, but after a while i ended up with this macro:

```
sub Conversionexcel
'
' Imprimir Macro

'actualizar MENU
rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
rem define variables
dim document   as object
dim dispatcher as object
rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
rem get access to the document
document   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")

dim args1(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
args1(0).Name = "Nr"
args1(0).Value = 1

dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:JumpToTable", "", 0, args1())
    

ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut From:=1, To:=1, Copies:=1

 
 
 
dim args2(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
args2(0).Name = "Nr"
args2(0).Value = 2

dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:JumpToTable", "", 0, args2())


end sub
```

it works, but the first time i run it every time i open the file it shows "BASIC runtime error.
Object variable not set." then i can delet a letter or some blank space, restore it, and then it works fine again.